# Why do moderators choose to not delete obvious off-topic questions after they have closed them?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, off-topic, moderators

I see this happen quite often, and while I don't agree/disagree, I am just wondering why.

Often on the sites I visit regularly (Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange), I see moderators closing obvious off-topic questions, but not deleting them. There is no way to salvage those posts, the only thing that can happen is that the author gets into an argument with other members about the closing.

So that made me wonder: why do moderators not hit the delete button right after they have closed such questions? Is it common practice or policy not to do so? What are the reasons behind it?

([Sample question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49727185/993547) for those interested)

Comment: Think it's because they (the moderators) don't have time to judge if it's salvageable or not. Better safe than sorry, so they give the author a chance to improve the question. Also, should make clear distinction between SO mods who are "ordinary people", and SE mods who are Stack Exchange employees.

Comment: But there is nothing to improve. Asking for a tool is off-topic (as acted on) and unsalvageable. @ShadowWizard

Comment: Like I said, they prefer to spend as little time as possible on things that can be moderated by ordinary users. And deciding if something is salvageable or not takes time, with hundreds of such flags/questions per day, it would simply take too much to ponder about each.

Comment: Also, for the record, here on MSE most of the times they do delete off topic questions right after closing them.

Comment: But why then close it? It is a new question. It would get picked up within minutes I guess.

Comment: @Sha Indeed. On MSE they tend to delete faster.

Comment: To give us a helping hand, but not doing all the job for us. All in all, I think you better ask this on MSO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard at smaller sites things are very different than at SO. And it probably much depends on how clear cut is the off-topic. At SE.SE for example certain kind off-topics tend to be quickly mod-deleted, see eg [Why was my question so quickly deleted by a moderator?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8351/31260)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deleting questions drastically reduces the visibility of the question and the moderator actions taken there. If the question stays undeleted by the moderator, the community can still act on it with the usual community moderation tools. Closure by a moderator can be reversed by the community, deletion can't be reversed without a moderator.

The automatic deletion is also pretty effective for anything that isn't upvoted or answered, so manual deletion is simply not necessary for those cases.

Sometimes I do immediately delete, but usually only if the question is either already causing trouble, or I expect it to do so. For example aggressive or insulting comments triggered by the topic.

Comment: I most often delete questions if they contain an advertisement.  Having it only closed means it would still be able to achieve its off-topic purpose.

Comment: @PolyGeo spam is typically not closed at all, but removed by spam flags, which do much more than just delete the post

Comment: I'm thinking of focused adverts rather than broadcast spam.  The sort of thing like a job description, call for open source project participants, etc that a new user might post before realizing that we are not "ask anything" sites. I think spam flags may be overkill for those.

Comment: This is pretty much the reasoning I use. Given a relatively new post I come across that needs closing I'll close it so that 1) the community can use their close votes elsewhere and 2) if it's in a less frequented tag it doesn't sit around in the CV queue (currently at 9.2k) for however long and 3) some hope the OP might read the reason and edit their post accordingly. For older resource requests (for example) that are attracting poor answers and are very likely to not get any care and attention and will only gather noise - I'll probably delete as well. Leave the rest to roomba & the community

Answer (score 4):

There are a few possible reasons here. If a post definitely cannot be saved, keeping it closed and visible does, hopefully, show an example of what we don't want on the site.

As long as it doesn't qualify for staying (upvoted answers etc) it will get removed automatically by the cleanup processes.

You mention arguments - believe me, removing causes far worse arguments than simply closing. It's better to make sure actions like this are visible.